# jquery selectors (finding tag)

Tags: jquery

I'm sure this is simple, but I can't seem to figure it out. I need to be able to pass a function an element id, and know what element tag it is.

For example:

```
<a id="first"></a>
<input id="last" />
```

If I know the id is "first", how can I get that the tag is "a"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var tagName = $("#first")[0].tagName;
```

The `[0]` is synonymous with `get(0)`. You get the first element from the jQuery object and use the DOM `tagName` property. It's arguably more straightforward in vanilla Javascript:

```
var tagName = document.getElementById("first").tagName;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the DOM property `tagName` like this:

```
document.getElementById('first').tagName
```

Or with jQuery, you would need to do:

```
$('#first')[0].tagName
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `.nodeName` here ([there are a few reasons this matters](http://aleembawany.com/2009/02/11/tagname-vs-nodename/)), like this:

```
$("#first").get(0).nodeName
//or the vanilla js way...
document.getElementById("first").nodeName
```

Comment: None of those differences are relevant here.

Comment: @cletus - True, but seeing as the OP doesn't know `.tagName` or `.nodeName` yet, I think it's best to point out the differences when first learning either.

Answer (score 1):

$("#first").attr("tagName");

Comment: @Jacob - Don't knock it :) http://jsfiddle.net/J8eUS/  But...I agree it's an over-use of jQuery in this case.

Comment: @Nick I still think is cleaner code. Readability vs Performance I guess? I usually do everything jqueryish when working with it, creates a code pattern of clean, concise code.